# Get the previous dates from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables.
1 table looks like this
(values are stored as DD-MM-YYYY)

Table A:

```
CustID | StartDate 
1      | 20-1-2016
2      | 25-1-2016
2      | 17-6-2016
```

Table B:

```
CustID  |  StartDate  |  EndDate
1       |  1-1-2016   |  15-1-2016
1       |  20-1-2016  |  1-4-2016
2       |  1-1-2015   |  1-6-2015
2       |  5-8-2015   |  31-12-2015
2       |  25-1-2016  |  31-5-2016
2       |  17-6-2016  |  31-12-2016
```

So what I want is to have all the data from table A. And find the previous date in table B. So in table B, out of every daterange before the startdate from table A, I want the highest EndDate .

So it would look like this:

Table Final:

```
CustID | TableA.StartDate |  TableB.EndDate (as Previous_date)
1      | 20-1-2016        |  15-1-2016
2      | 25-1-2016        |  31-12-2015
2      | 17-6-2016        |  31-5-2016
```

I hope this is sufficient amount of information to get some help. If you require more please let me know.

Comment: How you are storing date values ? Is it `DD-MM-YYYY` or `MM-DD-YYYY` format ? Or you are storing simply as Character type ? I am confused because you have one value in End Date- `1-15-2016` and `31-12-2015` too.

Comment: Value is stored as DD-MM-YYYY. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Then how you can have `1-15-2016` in EndDate ? Value for MM, i.e. Month, cannot be larger than `12`. Can you please check your data once again.

Comment: My mistake. Changed it now. Should give the right impression of the actual tables now.

Comment: Sooo... varchar dates? Or is the format just your NLS setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution would be like this: 
it would work, if you want to select other columns from your table B too.

```
SELECT A.id
      ,A.startdate
      ,B.enddate
   FROM tblA A
  INNER JOIN tblB B
     ON A.id = B.id
    AND B.startdate = (
                   SELECT TOP 1 startdate
                     FROM tblB subB
                    WHERE A.id = subB.ID
                      AND subB.startdate < A.startdate
                    ORDER BY startdate desc         
                      )
```

if you want to reproduce the result, here is a rextester link:
http://rextester.com/SGNX33699

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using the LAG analytic function:

```
WITH a AS (SELECT 1 custid, to_date('20/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') startdate FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 2 custid, to_date('25/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') startdate FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 2 custid, to_date('17/06/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') startdate FROM dual),
     b AS (SELECT 1 custid, to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') startdate, to_date('15/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') enddate FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 1 custid, to_date('20/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') startdate, to_date('01/04/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') enddate FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 2 custid, to_date('01/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') startdate, to_date('01/06/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') enddate FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 2 custid, to_date('05/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') startdate, to_date('31/12/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') enddate FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 2 custid, to_date('25/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') startdate, to_date('31/05/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') enddate FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 2 custid, to_date('17/06/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') startdate, to_date('31/12/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') enddate FROM dual),
    b2 AS (SELECT custid,
                  startdate,
                  enddate,
                  lag(enddate) OVER (PARTITION BY custid ORDER BY startdate) prev_enddate
           FROM   b)
SELECT a.custid,
       a.startdate,
       b2.prev_enddate
FROM   a
       INNER JOIN b2 ON a.startdate = b2.startdate;

    CUSTID STARTDATE   PREV_ENDDATE
---------- ----------- ------------
         1 20/01/2016  15/01/2016
         2 25/01/2016  31/12/2015
         2 17/06/2016  31/05/2016
```